# Difference between a CANopen device and a CANopen node

Tags: canopen

Is there a difference between a **CANopen device** and a **CANopen node**?

Answer (score 2):

The word "CANopen device" is used in the CANopen specificaiton (CiA-301) to describe an entity with its own node-ID, Object Dictionary and NMT state machine.

But then the word node is used to describe different services related to the CANopen device.

- Node control services, used to set the state of the CANopen device
- Node guarding protocol used to monitor the CANopen device
- Node-ID is the ID of the CANopen device.

So basically the word "CANopen node" does not exist in the CANopen specification, it uses the word "CANopen device". But the naming of the services and common language uses the word CANopen node to describe a CANopen device.

So they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

A CANopen device is the CANopen node. One CANopen device has one NODE-ID. One physical device could have more CANopen devices (more NODE-IDs).

There are also logical and virtual devices, but it is out of the current scope.

See standard CiA 301 chapter 4 for detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

is actually same. there is terminology difference, but basically they are same.

Answer (score 0):

A *CANopen device* is an entity that contains a CANopen protocol stack, an application software and an Object Dictionary. See [this description on the CiA website](https://www.can-cia.org/can-knowledge/canopen/device-architecture/).

A *CANopen node* is not officially defined but commonly used to describe any *CANopen device* that is connected to and part of a CANopen bus or network.

Nowadays, when you say "CANopen device" without further qualification, it means a non-managerial entity like those that were called "CANopen slave" before and you still find this expression in older standards and documentation. In contrast, a "CANopen manager" or "CANopen manager device" is one **with** managerial functions such as an NMT producer.

Answer (score -1):

A CANopen node is a CANopen device connected to a bus.